# Why are the aerial view maps so poor on my new Windows Phone 8

Tags: maps

Just moved from Windows Phone 7 on a HTC Trophy to Windows Phone 8 on an HTC 8X. Very please with most things, apart from the maps. Here is an aerial view map from my old phone:

[image]

And the same location on my new phone:

[image]

(These images are both Whitley Bay, UK if you want to test for yourself).
It looks like the images were taken on a cloudy day. It's rubbish!

The satellite imagery on my Windows Phone is very poor in general. It's better in London - but still poor compared to WP7.

Answer (score 2):

In Windows Phone 8 Microsoft has [switched](http://conversations.nokia.com/2012/10/31/frequently-asked-questions-maps-on-windows-phone-8/) from Bing to Nokia Maps for all of its data:

> **Is Nokia Maps on all Windows Phone 8 smartphones?**
>
> The Nokia Location Platform is powering the Windows Phone 8 ecosystem,
>   not Nokia Maps, which is an app. On non-Nokia Windows Phone 8
>   smartphones, the default mapping application is Windows Phone Maps.
>   **This is running on top of our map data. It is using our geocoding, our
>   traffic information and our routes**, but it’s ultimately developed by
>   Windows Phone, with a custom UI, search and POI database.

Apparently this provides more accurate information for some locations, but also worse for some--in my experience the maps are nigh unusable in Japan (using an HTC 8X).

If you are using a non-Nokia phone you get it slightly worse as some [features](http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/windows-phone-8-and-turn-turn-navigation) are only available in the Nokia Maps app e.g. public transportation and turn-by turn navigation (I believe this can work on non-Nokia phones with a plugin).